Where is thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity documentation located
Where can I find the official documentation of thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity?
I have searched the google for documentation but I am unable to find it. I have checked the official webpage of thymeleaf and also the GitHub repository of thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity and found nothing there.

Here is everything you need: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity

in the readme section there is not enough content for it to be called documentation it doesn't even cover the entire tag list let alone how thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity extra works so i don't think you can call that as doccumentation
